# Reading multiple values from reusable child components in it's parent component in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to create reusbale text/search input component in Vue 3.
Problem is that there will be cases in which I will be using this component in multiple places on the same parent and when I use example from Vue docs it uses the same value for all instances of my reusable input component.

App.vue:

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import MyComponent from './MyComponent.vue'
  
const myText = ref('')
</script>

<template>
  This input capitalizes everything you enter:<br />
  <MyComponent v-model.capitalize="myText" /><br />
  <MyComponent v-model.capitalize="myText" />
</template>
```

MyComponent.vue:

```
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  modelValue: String,
  modelModifiers: { default: () => ({}) }
})

const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])

function emitValue(e) {
  let value = e.target.value
  if (props.modelModifiers.capitalize) {
    value = value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1)
  }
  emit('update:modelValue', value)
}
</script>

<template>
  <input type="text" :value="modelValue" @input="emitValue" />
</template>
```

Does anyone know how can I make it so that the values in those inputs would be independent from eachother?

Comment: Looks like you are binding them all to the same variable (`myText`), right?

Comment: That is correct, I was looking for more elegant way of doing this rather than creating multiple variables. I managed to do so in vue 2

Comment: It seems that I managed to accomplish this in Vue 2 without being aware of it being a side effect of sorts. Perhaps using multiple variables is more beneficial due to it being potentially less problem prone.

Comment: The question is unclear. This totally depends on what you'll do with these values later. If you don't want to keep them  in separate variables, how are they supposed to be distinguished. "I managed to do so in vue 2" - how? This could give a hint on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It's not a side-effect, it is what you have written in your code, literally: When the value of `myText` changes, update it in the component instance, and write changes in the component back to the variable. That's what `v-model` does - two way binding. When you two-way bind the same variable to two components, those components share that state. Simple, right? Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: In vue2 my reusable inpout looked like this:

` :value="searchInpVal"`
`@input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"`
Then I simply used v-model and depending on which input I was editing, shared variable's value changed.

Comment: @MoritzRingler so this is not quite what I asked for but you are actually right, I missed one simple thing considering it's two way data binding :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to control this through a single variable, you should change the component structure and not use a v-model. You can set the input event that you will send from within the component, by capturing it in the parent, whenever you want. It is very difficult to handle this with a single variable in a structure bind using v-model.

In the component:

```js
const emit = defineEmits(['input'])

function emitValue(e) {
  let value = e.target.value
  if (props.modelModifiers.capitalize) {
    value = value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1)
  }
  emit('input', value)
}
```

In App.vue:

```js
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import MyComponent from './MyComponent.vue'
  
const myText = ref('')
const inputHandler = (input) => {
// do some logic and set value of myText
}
</script>

<template>
  This input capitalizes everything you enter:<br />
  <MyComponent @input="inputHandler" /><br />
  <MyComponent @input="inputHandler" />
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not define two `MyText` variables?

```
const myText1 = ref('')
const myText2 = ref('')
</script>

<template>
  This input capitalizes everything you enter:<br />
  <MyComponent v-model.capitalize="myText1" /><br />
  <MyComponent v-model.capitalize="myText2" />
</template>
```

This is straightforward and I would prefer a simple way instead of some tricking with Vue.js Reactivity/Events to achieve the same on one variable.

You could also use an object, if you don't want to have two variables.

Like this:

```
const myText = ref({ text1: '', text2: ''})

<template>
  This input capitalizes everything you enter:<br />
  <MyComponent v-model.capitalize="myText.text1" /><br />
  <MyComponent v-model.capitalize="myText.text2" />
</template>
```